# How to use different stylesheets for bootstrap 3 different views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use `mobile.css.less` for `mobile`, `wide.css.less` for `pc` view and so on. I know there's a class `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` and so on for `css classes`, but I'd like to use one of these features for `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="assets/css/mobile.css.less">` somehow. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you turning your .less files into .css when you serve the website?

Comment: @WillshawMedia should I do that (and if so - why?) and how can I do that?

Comment: Browsers can't interpret LESS files, they need to be converted into CSS in order for the browser to understand them. This can be done with Javascript when the page is rendered in the users browser, but it's better to do it before you push your site live, and just link to the CSS files. You can do this with programs like WinLESS (http://winless.org/) and SimpLESS (http://wearekiss.com/simpless) - but it's not specifically related to your question - just a tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using media queries to specify different certain screen sizes and pixel ratios to determine which style sheets should be used.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/mobile.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 901px)' href='css/wide.css' />
```

here's a good guide on it: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

You can use that in conjunction with the twitter bootstrap `hidden-xs` etc classes in a `general.css` as I imagine you'll have some common css across your theme.